# What is this device on my shower head?

Tags: shower

I moved into a house in northern Virginia and came across this device on the shower head in the master bath. It's about 4 inches across, maybe 3 inches deep. It has a dial that can turn and displays the name of a month in a little window.

There aren't similar devices in the other bathrooms. It does not seem to be part of the shower head itself because of the different finishes.

[image: shower head]

[image: close up]

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is a filter, probably activated charcoal, to remove residual chlorine. I doubt that it is necessary with the normal public water system. One sets the month when a new filter is installed as a reminder to change on some schedule.

Comment: Using @JimStewart's comment and [google image searching "shower filter month display"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=920&ei=odtLWuPtGs7k_Qas_LKQBQ&q=shower+filter+month+display&oq=shower+filter+month+display&gs_l=img.3...27992.33166.0.33262.27.12.0.15.4.0.136.1006.11j1.12.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..0.15.958...0j0i5i30k1j0i24k1.0.Mll6kRVPPqc) leads to [Sprite Showers Model # SL2-CM-R Universal Shower Filter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Sprite-Showers-Universal-Shower-Filter-in-Chrome-SL2-CM-R/202386562).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind is a filter, probably activated charcoal, to remove residual chlorine. I doubt that it is necessary with the normal public water system. One sets the month when a new filter is installed as a reminder to change on some schedule.

Such a filter must be changed on some schedule because over time a biofilm will build up on the filter cartridge.

Edit

The original poster located this unit https://www.homedepot.com/p/Sprite-Showers-Universal-Shower-Filter-in-Chrome-SL2-CM-R/202386562

Comment: the link does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

It's likely a copper media filter for chlorine only, not a particulate filter.  I believe copper alters chlorine to something less smelly and drying. Occasionally shake it to keep it working.